# unix tty hang after tail with acute (`)

Tags: linux, ls, tail, unix-head

Hi i run a command on Linux server.

```
tail -3 `ls -1t nnnn* | head -1`
```

When nnnn file exist, all good.

When nnnn file not exist the tty is hanged until ^C

```
nt-home-stg>> tail -3 `ls -1t nnnn* | head -1`
ls: No match.
```

After the `ls: No match.` it hangs until ctrl c (^c) is pressed.

I've searched the web and could not find an answer.

Already tried the traditional suppress `>& /dev/null` and `2>/dev/null`
. Did not help.

Is there a way for the command to end and not hang?

Comment: Incidentally, \` is not an "acute"; an acute accent would point the other way, and wouldn't exist on its own anyway. It's commonly called a "backtick".

Comment: @IMSoP Not trying to argue, but I took the name from here http://www.computerhope.com/keys.htm 
Just to act like pro :) I BTW Know it by the name 'back quote'.

Comment: Yeah, that website is kind of ... wrong. They list it as both [grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) and [acute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent), which are definitely not the same thing. It also says it doesn't exist on phone keyboards, when it's perfectly easy to find on the default Google Android keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

The backtick syntax substitutes the output of the given command; when that command returns a filename, you get something like:

```
tail -3 nnnn01.whatever
```

But if there are no matches, there is nothing to substitute, so you effectively run:

```
tail -3
```

If we look at the summary under `man tail`, we see the behaviour if `tail` is not given a filename:

> With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

So `tail` is waiting for some input to be piped in, and it will then display the last 3 lines of that input. You can actually type a few lines of text, and press Ctrl-D ("end of file"), and you'll see it happen.

This may seem pointless, but the command doesn't know (or care) that it's been invoked directly, and not as part of a pipeline. So the `head -1` in your inner query is actually doing the same thing: reading standard input because you didn't give a file name.

To avoid this, you should test that your file exists first, before running tail. A non-elegant way of writing that on one line would be to capture the filename in a variable, and use `[` (aka `test`) to assert that it is non-empty:

```
(file=`ls -1t nnnn* | head -1`; [ -n "$file" ] && tail -3 $file)
```

This will still give you the warning from `ls` that the glob failed, but will skip the hanging `tail`.

Comment: Thanks - is there a way to not wait for standard input. and just end the command in such case?

Comment: @ReDevil I'd say the best approach would be to test your file exists first. A non-elegant way of writing that on one line: `(file=$(ls -1t nnnn* | head -1); [ -n "$file" ] && tail -3 $file)` (Using `$(...)` instead of backticks, because Markdown makes me sad, but also because I prefer that style anyway.)